# How do I treat a System.Devices.ClassGuid null reference exception?

Tags: c#, system

I run the following code taken from a [device explorer](https://github.com/smourier/DeviceExplorer):

```
    private async void OnDeviceAdded(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformation device)
    {
        var information = await GetInformationAsync(device).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var classGuid = (Guid)information.Properties["System.Devices.ClassGuid"];

        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            var classItem = Children.Cast<DeviceClassItem>().FirstOrDefault(i => i.ClassGuid == classGuid);
            if (classItem == null)
            {
                classItem = new DeviceClassItem(this, classGuid);
                Children.Add(classItem);
            }

            classItem.AddDevice(information, device);
        });
    }
```

It throws an exception trying to look for System.Devices.ClassGuid.

I would to know if I have to completely discard the object because I would not be able to use it, and I should just try-catch the exception, and or is there anything else that I need to do to properly handle this exception?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: If you don't want to throw exception, then try `var classGuid = (Guid?)information?.Properties?["System.Devices.ClassGuid"];`

Comment: @Greg Then it throws an error here: classItem = new DeviceClassItem(this, classGuid); It says: Can't convert System-Guid? to System.Guid.

Comment: You can add `.Value` . E.g: `new DeviceClassItem(this, classGuid.Value)` - if the Guid is null, then the following should also be null `(classItem == null)` (if not add a null check for Guid)